# Some problems with numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```py
li = np.array(list("123"))
li[0] = "fff"
print(li)
```

prints `['f' '2' '3']` and not `['fff' '2' '3']`. Why so? How can I tune/fix it?

Comment: Hint: what is the `dtype` of `li`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why so?**

Some debugging will help here. Take the first line for example:

```
>>> li = np.array(list("123"))
```

Then what is `li`?

```
>>> li
array(['1', '2', '3'], dtype='<U1')
```

Note the datatype of `li`, `<U1`, the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) explain that this datatype is for a unicode string of length 1. `numpy` has chosen this type for you, based on the elements you provided in the constructor, in order that it can allocate memory for `li` and probably do some optimisation in the background.

What happens when you do `li[0] = "fff"` then, since `"fff"` is not a unicode string of length 1? Then, `numpy` will convert `"fff"` to a unicode string of length 1, which in this case, appears to be `"f"`.

```
>>> li[0] = "fff"
>>> li
array(['f', '2', '3'], dtype='<U1')
```

Now the `print` output should make sense.

**What to do about it**

You can explicitly pass a datatype when you construct your array. E.g.

```
>>> li = np.array(list("123"), dtype="<U3")
>>> li
array(['1', '2', '3'], dtype='<U3')
>>> li[0] = "fff"
>>> li
array(['fff', '2', '3'], dtype='<U3')
```

You will of course then have to decide in advance which type the array really will be, in this case, the maximum length of the string you can have is 3.

If you can make no guarantees about the types in the array, consider instead using a `list` instead of a `numpy.array` as a data structure.